# Synchronizing Kie Workbench

Tags: kie-workbench, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I am new to Drools and Kie Workbench. I have Kie workbench running on tomcat Server.

I am looking for Clustering Kie Workbench, because the same project will be running on three different tomcat server (each server will have respective Workbench) pointing different DB (Region specific like India, America).
Now if i make any change in project like adding rule at run-time in any of the server, It should automatically synchronize the project in other two servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cluster git repository of kie-workbench you have to use zookeeper and Helix. Go through [link](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR2/drools-docs/html/wb.WorkbenchHighAvailability.html) for more details about kie-workbench git repository cluster.